# Count number of pixels satisfying different conditions in an online layer within a polygon

Tags: raster, spatial-analyst, arcgis-online

**Raster file**-> Terrain: Slope in Degrees in ArcGIS Online, by ESRI

**Shapefile**-> US Census Tracts in Census 2000, downloaded from NHGIS

I would like to have more information about the distribution of slope within a certain census tract (each of them is a polygon). In particular, how many pixels satisfy different conditions (e.g. slope between 0-5%, between 5-10%, 10-15, >15) and also calculate the range of slope within the polygon.

I've done something like this before using Con and Zonal Statistics as Table but it meant having use the Python console to create a different raster for every possible category and that would take too long (also lots of HDD space). Also, I don't know how to do this with ArcGIS Online Layers since they are huge (this one is about 1.5TB), so maybe there is another option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone else has the same question, this is what I ended up doing.

Instead of using Terrain: Slope in Degrees, I used the Land Surface Forms developed by the USGS, which basically categorizes each pixel by their slope and elevation range.

After this, the quickest (but memory intensive) option is to use the **isectpolyrst** command of the **Geospatial Modelling Environment** toolbox for ArcGIS 10.3. Unfortunately, my computer does not have that much memory (the raster is about 20gb) so I opted for using R instead.

In R you can use the **extract()** function to do the trick. The code is still running and I really hope it will deliver what I'm looking for (I'll post updates).